# Display Entries Belonging to User

Tags: entries

I'm trying to group entries by user on my front-end. I've got so far but I can't seem to get any further to my goal of `displaying what type of entries they have posted e.g. lifestyle or tech.` to do this I need to get the `users entries` and query a `service` dropdown field, if they have `lifestyle` selected in multiple entries only display 1x tag showing the user has `lifestyle` posts.

So far I'm just trying to query each user's entries.

```
{% set listings = craft.entries.section('listings') %}
{% set users = craft.users.group('influencer').all() %}


      {% for user in users %}

          {% if user.getPhoto() %}
              <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="{{ user.getPhoto().getUrl('thumbnail') }}">
          {% else %}
              <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="{{ url('images/user-ph.png') }}">
          {% endif %}

            <h5 class="card-title">{{ user.username }}</h5>
            <small>{{ user.location }}</small>
            <p class="card-text">{{ user.richText }}</p>

        {% for user, entries in craft.entries.find() | group('users') %}
          {% for entry in entries %}
            {{ entry.title }}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the easiest way to fetch the user's entries is to do something like this:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.authorId(user.id) %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

The way this works is you fetch all the entries that were authored by the current `user` in your main `for` loop by using `authorId(user.id)`. In my opinion, this is a lot cleaner and more performant over what you were trying to accomplish with the  `group` filter.

---

Now, to answer your question; here's how I would solve it.

First, create an empty array:

```
{% set services = [] %}
```

Then, inside your user's entries `for` loop, we'd grab the value of the service field (for each entry) and see if it exists in the `services` array. If not, we'll merge it in.

```
{% set dropdown = entry.service.label %}
{% if dropdown not in services %}
     {% set services = services | merge([ dropdown ]) %}
{% endif %}
```

Then we can use this array to display whatever we want on the frontend:

```
{% for item in services %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

So, all together:

```
{% set users = craft.users.group('influencer').all() %}

{% for user in users %}

    {% if user.getPhoto() %}
        <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="{{ user.getPhoto().getUrl('thumbnail') }}">
    {% else %}
        <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="{{ url('images/user-ph.png') }}">
    {% endif %}

    <h5 class="card-title">{{ user.username }}</h5>
    <small>{{ user.location }}</small>
    <p class="card-text">{{ user.richText }}</p>

    {% set entries = craft.entries.authorId(user.id) %}
    {% set services = [] %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {% set dropdown = entry.services.label %}
        {% if dropdown not in services %}
            {% set services = services | merge([ dropdown ]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for item in services %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```